# Adding a field to a list of dictionaries based on another field value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionary in the form of

```
[{'a': '2.1', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'banana'}, {'a': '4.7', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'banana'}, {'a': '1.6', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'orange'}]
```

I am looking to add another field to each dictionary whose value depends on value of another field and the final list should look like

```
[{'a': '2.1', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'banana', 'm':'anana'}, {'a': '4.7', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'banana', 'm':'anana'}, {'a': '1.6', 'z': 'apple', 'aa': 'orange', 'm':'range'}]
```

The first letter of the key 'aa' is removed and added to another field.

I did it by

```
for x in val:
    x['m'] = x['aa'][1:]
```

Is this can be done using a single line operation

Comment: Your current solution is perfectly OK. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I feel there is a misunderstanding about what are those "one-liners".
I, myself, proudly exhibit one of those from times to times, in answer to some questions.

But, in reality, it is not the fact that they fit on 1 line that makes them "pythonesque". But the fact that they are expression, not instruction. That is, some sort of functional programming, which is part of the multi-paradigms of python.

So if your question were

> I need to build a new list of whose fields are the same of another one, plus a new field, computed from another field.
> For now my solution is
>
> ```py
> newdics=[]
> for d in val:
>     nd=d.copy()
>     nd['m'] = nd['aa][1:]
>     newdics.append(nd)
> ```

Then, we could have answered with a spectacular one liner such as

```py
newdics=[dict(d, m=d['aa'][1:]) for d in val]
```

(Which is roughly the answer you got while I was typing this one, without the `**{'keyword':value}` usage, and a simple `keyword=value` instead, as argument for `dict` — note that `**{'keyword':value}` might be a good idea if in reality you have a bunch of rules saying what are those keywords, themselves computed. But in your question, that keyword is simply `m`, so it is even more compact to just add `m=...` to `dict` argument, rather than `**{'m': ...}`)

Then, that one-liner would have been useful, because, it replace a whole code, using intermediates variables, whose only purpose would be to compute an expression, by a single expression.

But that is not your question. Your question is to replace a 2-lines imperative instruction by a 1-line imperative instruction. One-liner in such situation doesn't really help. It is still an instruction. It does not avoid imperative style to perform a functional operation.

But, well, if you really insist on having a single line, rather than the functional

```py
[dict(d, m=d['aa'][1:]) for d in val]
```

that does not exactly the same as what you wanted, I would simply remind that in python, when a "subblock" is only one line, you can put it in the same line.
So, simply format your code that way

```py
for x in val: x['m'] = x['aa'][1:]
```

It is even shorter than my functional one-liner (and therefore even shorter than Nuri's), and it has the advantage to do exactly what you wanted: not compute a value, but change the one you have; an instruction, not an expression.